# How to profile pgSQL functions?

Tags: performance, postgresql, profiling, plpgsql

I have a script written in pgSQL that moves records from one table to others. The logic is quite sophisticated: it involves lots of SELECT queries. For readability, the script is divided into many functions calling one another.

I would like to find a bottleneck in the script.

I tried to use pgbadger to find the most time-consuming queries. I enabled logging according to the instructions from https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger/blob/master/README (POSTGRESQL CONFIGURATION section). But the problem is that pgbadger relies on logs and the logs are on the level of pgSQL functions, not single SELECT statements. So the information I get is that running a given function took X seconds. I would like to see a chart that shows how much time every SELECT query was running. Is there a way to do it without reorganizing the script?

Comment: I think [`pg_stat_statements`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgstatstatements.html) should do it, though I've never tried it myself

Comment: Rewrite the functions to prepared statements and profile these, using the same arguments. (the syntax for functions and prepared statement is almost the same)

Comment: Thanks, pg_stat_statements is what I looked for.